# Optical drive not recognized after 14.04 update

Tags: cd-drive, optical

Just installed updates in 14.04. Prior to updates the CD\DVD drive was recognized by both admin and standard user accounts. After updates can only access in admin. Standard user message is don't have required permissions. How do I set permissions for standard user to CD/DVD drive?

Answer (score 0):

The cd/dvd cd should be "mounted" at the /media/user
So, type in your terminal:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

then input your root password. After that, navigate to Computer.
Find your /media and Right Click -> Properties. At the permission tab, you can change the permission for "Others" to "access files". If you have more than one standard user, you can do the same to only a desired user.